# Getting 403 error when trying to add new tenant

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I added a service provider to WSO2IS and use its secret to get an access token, I then use this access token to execute endpoint https://localhost:9443/t/carbon.super/api/server/v1/tenants, but I am getting 403 error. An access token is for the admin user, that as far as I see has all privileges. Why am I getting a forbidden error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you please add the error log also?

Comment: @positron Have you passed the required scopes when generating an access token? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65371473/10055162. Please confirm that you have passed the required scopes to invoke the mentioned API. Please add the request you used to generate the access token

Comment: Thank you, @AnuradhaKarunarathna that was the issue, and you did mention it before - I forgot about it. Please answer the question so I can mark it as solution.

Comment: @sumedhe I looked at different logs, but they gave no clue about the error, I looked in /repository/logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the steps in https://stackoverflow.com/a/65371473/10055162. If you generated the token without passing the required scopes (In your case `internal_list_tenants`), you will get `403 Forbidden` response from the REST API call. More info ([3](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/authenticating-and-authorizing-rest-apis/#scope-based-authorization-for-rest-apis))